# Why my Leap Year Code in C is not working?

Tags: c

When I enter a year the program isn't execute

I will wait for exciting this program.  But id won't execute.
When I press enter it contain line break but won't work.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(){

    int year;
    scanf("%d\n",&year);

    if(year%400==0||(year%100==0&&year%4==0))

        printf("%d is Leap Year",year);

    else
        printf("%d Not Leap Year",year);

    return 0;
}
```

Sample:
[image: Sample]

Comment: Remove the `\n` from `scanf("%d\n",&year);`  --> `scanf("%d",&year);`

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `\n` will eat *all* following whitespace until non-whitespace characters appear or end of file is met.

Comment: owo ! it's working thank you a lot .  – Achal

Comment: Also, **read carefully the documentation of *every* function that you are using.** [scanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) is *documented* to return an item count, and you should use and test it. And don't forget to add a `\n` at the end of every [printf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), because `stdout` is *usually* line-buffered.

Comment: Your formula `year%100==0&&year%4==0` is wrong, formally *and* functionally.

Comment: I think the correct condition is `if ( year % 4 == 0 && ( year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0 ) )`. Also `math.h` is not necessary. About `scanf` and `\n` is already discussed.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%d\n",&year);` means: read optional whitespace (any amount) followed by an integer (`%d`) followed by any amount of whitespace (`\n`).

So after you type `[SPACE][TAB][ENTER]` the function consumes those 3 characters and is still "stuck" in the first whitespace reading.

You then type `[SPACE][TAB]2000[ENTER]` and the function consumes those 7 characters, assignes 2000 to `year` and gets "stuck" in the second whitespace reading.
Type a few more `[SPACE][TAB][ENTER]` and it is still "stuck".

Finally, type `[SPACE]"Z"[ENTER]` to have the function consume this last space until it gets to the "Z" which (along with `[ENTER]`) remains unconsumed in the input buffer.